# Google Map Camera Position Not change In Marshmallow android

Tags: android, dictionary, gps

I have application of android for booking taxi I create app like uber app .
it works fine on all  version in india but not working on UK  also Google map and Geocoder Service  not working  on 6.0.1. android Marshmallow

I have code

```
     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {

LinearLayout btnview, destview;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE = 1;
int PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    userSession = new UserSession(this);
    userdetails = userSession.getUserDetails();
    username = userdetails.get(UserSession.KEY_USERNAME);
    userdefaultaddr = userdetails.get(UserSession.KEY_ADDR);
    View v = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView.setText(username);

    mContext = this;
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    btnview = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.locationbutton);
    destview = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.destination_view);
    btnsearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchcab_button);
    mdestinationaddr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.desti_txt);
    mLocationMarkerText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.locationMarkertext);
    mLocationText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Locality);
    mLocationText.setText("" + userdefaultaddr);
    mLocationText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openAutocompleteActivity();
        }
    });
    mdestinationaddr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            try {
                Intent intent =
                        new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
                                .build(MainActivity.this);
                startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                // TODO: Handle the error.
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                // TODO: Handle the error.
            }
        }
    });
    mLocationMarkerText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            btnview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            destview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mLocationMarkerText.setText("SET DESTINATION LOCATION");
        }
    });
    btnsearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            fromloc = mLocationText.getText().toString();
            toloc = mdestinationaddr.getText().toString();
            // traveldate=datepick_btn.getText().toString();
            //traveltime=timepick_btn.getText().toString();

            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
            SimpleDateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
            traveldate = df1.format(c.getTime());
            traveltime = df2.format(c.getTime());

            if (fromloc != null && toloc != null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);
                //  intent.putExtra("listdata", cablistdata);
                intent.putExtra("s", fromloc);
                intent.putExtra("d", toloc);
                intent.putExtra("dt", traveldate);
                intent.putExtra("tm", traveltime);
                startActivity(intent);
                // searchCabs(fromloc, toloc, traveldate, traveltime);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Enter Source and Destination", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    mResultReceiver = new AddressResultReceiver(new Handler());
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkLocationPermission();
        buildGoogleApiClient();
    }
    if (checkPlayServices()) {

        if (!AppUtils.isLocationEnabled(mContext)) {
            // notify user
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
            dialog.setMessage("Location not enabled!");
            dialog.setPositiveButton("Open location settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            });
            dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
        buildGoogleApiClient();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Location not supported in this device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    Intent background = new Intent(this, BackgroundService.class);
    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, background, 0);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis(), 30 * 1000, pintent);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_history) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BookHistoryActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GeneralActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("from", "settings");
        startActivity(intent);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_notification) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GeneralActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("from", "notific");
        startActivity(intent);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_payment) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GeneralActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("from", "payment");
        startActivity(intent);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_promotions) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GeneralActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("from", "promo");
        startActivity(intent);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GeneralActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("from", "about");
        startActivity(intent);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_help) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GeneralActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("from", "help");
        startActivity(intent);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {
        userSession.logoutUser();
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BaseActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    Log.d(TAG, "OnMapReady");
    mMap = googleMap;

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


            mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
                    Log.d("Camera postion change" + "", cameraPosition + "");
                    mCenterLatLong = cameraPosition.target;

                    mMap.clear();

                    try {

                        Location mLocation = new Location("");
                        mLocation.setLatitude(mCenterLatLong.latitude);
                        mLocation.setLongitude(mCenterLatLong.longitude);

                        startIntentService(mLocation);
                        // mLocationMarkerText.setText("Lat : " + mCenterLatLong.latitude + "," + "Long : " + mCenterLatLong.longitude);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    } else {

        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
    mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
            Log.d("Camera postion change" + "", cameraPosition + "");
            mCenterLatLong = cameraPosition.target;

            mMap.clear();

            try {

                Location mLocation = new Location("");
                mLocation.setLatitude(mCenterLatLong.latitude);
                mLocation.setLongitude(mCenterLatLong.longitude);

                startIntentService(mLocation);
                // mLocationMarkerText.setText("Lat : " + mCenterLatLong.latitude + "," + "Long : " + mCenterLatLong.longitude);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    //   mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
   // mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                    mGoogleApiClient);
            Log.d("inmarshlastloc", "" + mLastLocation.getLatitude() + "/" + mLastLocation.getLongitude());
            if (mLastLocation != null) {
                changeMap(mLastLocation);
                Log.d(TAG, "ON connected");

            } else
                try {
                    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                            mGoogleApiClient, this);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            try {
                LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
                mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
                mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
                mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                        mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } else {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

    Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);

    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        changeMap(mLastLocation);
        Log.d(TAG, "ON connected");

    } else
        try {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient, this);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    try {
        LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection suspended");

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            return;
        }
        return;
    } else {

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    try {
        if (location != null)
            Log.d("inmarsh", "" + location.getLatitude() + "/" + location.getLongitude());
        changeMap(location);
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, this);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    try {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    try {

    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            //finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private void changeMap(Location location) {

    Log.d(TAG, "Reaching map" + mMap);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            if (mMap != null) {
                mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
                LatLng latLong;

                Log.d("inmarshchangemap", "" + location.getLatitude() + "/" + location.getLongitude());
                latLong = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(latLong).zoom(19f).build();

                //  mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                        .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

                // mLocationMarkerText.setText("Lat : " + location.getLatitude() + "," + "Long : " + location.getLongitude());
                startIntentService(location);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    } else {

        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
    // check if map is created successfully or not
    if (mMap != null) {
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
        LatLng latLong;

        latLong = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(latLong).zoom(19f).build();

        //  mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        // mLocationMarkerText.setText("Lat : " + location.getLatitude() + "," + "Long : " + location.getLongitude());
        startIntentService(location);

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
}

@SuppressLint("ParcelCreator")
class AddressResultReceiver extends ResultReceiver {
    public AddressResultReceiver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
    }

    /**
     * Receives data sent from FetchAddressIntentService and updates the UI in MainActivity.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {

        // Display the address string or an error message sent from the intent service.
        mAddressOutput = resultData.getString(AppUtils.LocationConstants.RESULT_DATA_KEY);

        mAreaOutput = resultData.getString(AppUtils.LocationConstants.LOCATION_DATA_AREA);

        mCityOutput = resultData.getString(AppUtils.LocationConstants.LOCATION_DATA_CITY);
        mStateOutput = resultData.getString(AppUtils.LocationConstants.LOCATION_DATA_STREET);

        displayAddressOutput();

        // Show a toast message if an address was found.
        if (resultCode == AppUtils.LocationConstants.SUCCESS_RESULT) {
            //  showToast(getString(R.string.address_found));
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Updates the address in the UI.
 */
protected void displayAddressOutput() {
    //  mLocationAddressTextView.setText(mAddressOutput);
    try {
        if (mAreaOutput != null)
            // mLocationText.setText(mAreaOutput+ "");

            mLocationText.setText(mAddressOutput);
        //  mLocationText.setText(mAreaOutput);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Creates an intent, adds location data to it as an extra, and starts the intent service for
 * fetching an address.
 */
protected void startIntentService(Location mLocation) {
    // Create an intent for passing to the intent service responsible for fetching the address.
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, FetchAddressIntentService.class);

    // Pass the result receiver as an extra to the service.
    intent.putExtra(AppUtils.LocationConstants.RECEIVER, mResultReceiver);

    // Pass the location data as an extra to the service.
    intent.putExtra(AppUtils.LocationConstants.LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA, mLocation);

    // Start the service. If the service isn't already running, it is instantiated and started
    // (creating a process for it if needed); if it is running then it remains running. The
    // service kills itself automatically once all intents are processed.
    startService(intent);
}

private void openAutocompleteActivity() {
    try {
        // The autocomplete activity requires Google Play Services to be available. The intent
        // builder checks this and throws an exception if it is not the case.
        Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
                .build(this);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
        // Indicates that Google Play Services is either not installed or not up to date. Prompt
        // the user to correct the issue.
        GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, e.getConnectionStatusCode(),
                0 /* requestCode */).show();
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        // Indicates that Google Play Services is not available and the problem is not easily
        // resolvable.
        String message = "Google Play Services is not available: " +
                GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorString(e.errorCode);

        Toast.makeText(mContext, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

/**
 * Called after the autocomplete activity has finished to return its result.
 */
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Check that the result was from the autocomplete widget.
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Get the user's selected place from the Intent.
            Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(mContext, data);

            // TODO call location based filter

            LatLng latLong;

            latLong = place.getLatLng();
            mLocationText.setText(place.getName() + "");

           /* if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }*/
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                            .target(latLong).zoom(19f).build();

                    // mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                            .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                }
            } else {

                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(latLong).zoom(19f).build();

            // mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        }
    }     
}

public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
```

planation, try again to request the permission.

```
            //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
            //(just doing it here for now, note that with this code, no explanation is shown)
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);

        } else {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                          if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }

            } else {                  
                Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }          
    }
}
  }
```

Please Help me on this
Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

Successfully Solved. i was also worried about this issue my app was working on lolipop and below on nougat but not on marshamallow.so i solved in this way.

I have solved it just getting permission before this activity and remove from onmapready funtion.

1.You are checking permissions at run time for locations permission in onmapready  function remove from this function and call before this activity . hopefully it will work otherwise comment below .

2.remove location manager , method its permissions and removecallbackmethods. then it will work.on connected connected fused api..then it will work perfect.

just comment the permission onmapready like this.

add super lint option on pressing alt_ enter on mapenabledtrue.

```
 @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
{
    mGoogleMap=googleMap;
    mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    buildGoogleApiClient();
    mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    //Initialize Google Play Services
   /* if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //Location Permission already granted
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {
            //Request Location Permission
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
    }
    else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }*/
}
```